# How to apply Onclick on my dropdown [ codeigniter ]

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, codeigniter

I have a dropdown list then submit form when you click select values from dropdown

using this code

```
 onchange="this.form.submit()"
```

But I don't know how to put this on my dropdown check my code below,

```
<?php foreach($options as $key_option=>$val_option):?>
    <div class="col-lg-3">
        <label class="control-label">
            <?php echo $required_notice.$val_option['option']?>
            <?php if(!empty($options_lang[$key][$key_option]->hint)):?>
            <i class="icon-question-sign hint" data-hint="
                <?php echo $options_lang[$key][$key_option]->hint;?>">
            </i>
            <?php endif;?>
        </label>
        <?php
        if(isset($options_lang[$key][$key_option])){
            $drop_options = array_combine(explode(',',check_combine_set(isset($options_lang[$key])?$options_lang[$key][$key_option]->values:'', $val_option['values'], '')),explode(',',check_combine_set($val_option['values'], isset($options_lang[$key])?$options_lang[$key][$key_option]->values:'', '')));
        } else {
            $drop_options = array();
        }

        // If you don't want translation to website langauge uncomment this 1 line below:
        // $drop_options = array_combine(explode(',', $options_lang[$key][$key_option]->values), explode(',', $options_lang[$key][$key_option]->values));

        $drop_selected = set_value('option'.$val_option['id'].'_'.$key, isset($estate['option'.$val_option['id'].'_'.$key])?$estate['option'.$val_option['id'].'_'.$key]:'');
        echo form_dropdown ('option'.$val_option['id'].'_'.$key, $drop_options, $drop_selected, 'class="form-control" id="inputOption_'.$key.'_'.$val_option['id'].'" placeholder="'.$val_option['option'].'" '.$required_text)            
        ?>
    </div>undefined</div>
<?php endforeach;?>
```

***Output***

[image]

Thankyou

NOTE: My dropdown is inside a foreach

Answer (score 0):

You should put your onchange prop into your `form_dropdown` function so your select option will have the event you want, submit while option changed.

```
<div class="col-lg-3">
    <label class="control-label">
        <?php echo $required_notice.$val_option['option']?>
        <?php if(!empty($options_lang[$key][$key_option]->hint)):?>
        <i class="icon-question-sign hint" data-hint="
            <?php echo $options_lang[$key][$key_option]->hint;?>">
        </i>
        <?php endif;?>
    </label>
    <?php
      if(isset($options_lang[$key][$key_option]))
          {
              $drop_options = array_combine(explode(',',check_combine_set(isset($options_lang[$key])?$options_lang[$key][$key_option]->values:'', $val_option['values'], '')),explode(',',check_combine_set($val_option['values'], isset($options_lang[$key])?$options_lang[$key][$key_option]->values:'', '')));
          }
      else
          {
              $drop_options = array();
          }

                  // If you don't want translation to website langauge uncomment this 1 line below:
                  // $drop_options = array_combine(explode(',', $options_lang[$key][$key_option]->values), explode(',', $options_lang[$key][$key_option]->values));

              $drop_selected = set_value('option'.$val_option['id'].'_'.$key, isset($estate['option'.$val_option['id'].'_'.$key])?$estate['option'.$val_option['id'].'_'.$key]:'');

              echo form_dropdown ('option'.$val_option['id'].'_'.$key, $drop_options, $drop_selected, 'onchange="this.form.submit()" class="form-control" id="inputOption_'.$key.'_'.$val_option['id'].'" placeholder="'.$val_option['option'].'" '.$required_text)

      ?>
</div>undefined</div>
```

Comment: I try this one, but it becomes loop or even I'm not doing anything my form keeps submitting

Comment: It's because my dropdown is inside a foreach loop? Because I call my form using foreach

Comment: Btw, where's your <form> wrapper?

Comment: from the top of foreach here's my form-wrapper
<?php echo form_open(NULL, array('class' => 'form-horizontal form-estate', 'role'=>'form', 'id'=>'property-submition'))?>

Comment: Its weird, did you try using jquery instead? $('select[id^="inputOption_"]').change(function(){ $(this).parents('form').submit() })

Comment: I try some test.

I do simple  select 
<select onchange="this.form.submit()" >
  <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  <option value="opel">Opel</option>
  <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>

this one works fine but when I try to apply on form with php it becomes loop